# method not getting called on onclick event

Tags: html, jsf-2, checkbox, onclick

I am createing page using JSF 2.0:

```xml
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox1" title="Published" 
                         onclick="#{StageGate.setMyCheckboxValue()}" />
```

I was expecting `setMyCheckboxValue()` to be called whenever checkbox is clicked. However, `setMyCheckboxValue()` is called once when page is loaded.

If I write

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox1" title="Published" 
onclick="#{StageGate.setMyCheckboxValue()}; alert(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked);" />
```

I get alert for each click.

My Question is: When I am getting alert, why `setMyCheckboxValue()` is not getting called on each onclick event?

**Note:** I also tried AJAX, but the checkbox remains constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick` attribute is for client side (javascript) methods and will not change anything on the server side.

If you want to change a server side value you need the `value` attribute:

```html
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{StageGate.myCheckboxValue}" .../>
```

Note that I changed your `setMyCheckboxValue()` to `myCheckboxValue` because the setter method is automatically detected by jsf (if you correctly define your variable `foo` with the getter `getFoo()` and the setter `setFoo(...)`)

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is used for client side javascript calls.
I think you want to call a function on server side, when a checkbox is clicked.

Here is the code:

```xml
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox1" title="Published"
                         value="#{StageGate.myCheckBox}" >
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"
            action="#{StageGate.setMyCheckboxValue()}" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: when I use ajax, the problem is that if the checkbox is selected when loaded then it remains checked even after clicking...